# WebView delegate method - shouldStartLoadWithRequest receives request in lower case

Tags: ios, webview

When i was working with the hybrid application where in HTML is sending the url with i need to load in the WebView. But the problem is for some specific url im receiving the request in all lower case. Actually the HTML url are encoded one and sending it to the native but problem is when i decode it is giving as null. Because it is not in the same encoded format as it is done in HTML side. I have check in the HTML side through the alert before sending it to the native it contains both upper and lower case but when i receive it in the delegate method im getting oly lower case letter. Because of which im not able to get the encoded data properly which i cannot decode them in the proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us peace of code

Comment: - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *) webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest    *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
 In the request im recieving everything in lowercase.